# Time complexity in Divide and conquer algorithms

Tags: c, algorithm, divide-and-conquer

Could you please help me in understanding the Time Complexity for Divide and Conquer algorithm.

Let's take example of this one.
http://www.geeksforgeeks.org/archives/4583 Method 2:
It gave T(n) = 3/2n -2  and i don't understand why?

I am sorry, if i gave you an extra page to open too but i really wanna understand atleast to a good high level so that i can find the complexity of such algorithms on my own, You answer is highly appreciated.

Comment: Well to explain that, we would actually need to know your current understanding level. For example, your strength on Recursive Algorithm and Complexity analysis in general. I would suggest you try to look up some interactive slides.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Can't open this link due to some reason. I'll still give it a try.
When you use the divide and conquer strategy, what you do is you break up the problem into many smaller problems and then you combine the solutions for the small problems to get the solution for the main problem. 
How to solve the smaller problems: By breaking them up further. This process of breaking up continues until you reach a level where the problem is small enough to be handled directly.

How to compute time complexity:
Assume the time taken by your algo is T(n). Notice that time taken is a function of the problem size i.e. n.

Now, notice what you are doing. You break up the problems into let's say k parts each of size n/k (they may not be equal in size, in which case you'll have to add the time taken by them individually). Now, you'll solve these k parts. Time taken by each part would be T(n/k) because the problem size is reduced to n/k now. And you are solving k of these. So, it takes k * T(n/k) time.

After solving these smaller problems, you'll combine their solutions. This will also take some time. And that time will be a function of your problem size again. (It could also be constant). Let that time be O(f(n)).

So, total time taken by your algorithm will be:
T(n) = (k * T(n/k)) + O(f(n))

You've got a recurrence relation now which you can solve to get T(n).

Comment: Feel free to ask for clarifications.

Comment: Thanks Divya. Ya, i went to that website and looks like it has reached to it's capacity and thus unable 2 provide service. 

Actually what you explained i already knew till that part but, its the math here which is confusing me.
But lemme reach over to my old college books and try to understand.

Thanks a lot for your time.

Comment: If you are looking for "how to solve recurrence relations", you may want to check this link http://www.cs.ucr.edu/~jiang/cs141/recur-tut.txt It is a quick tutorial which covers various methods to solve recurrence relations. Happy to help! :) @Leoheart

Answer (score 2):

As this link indicate:

```
  T(n) = T(floor(n/2)) + T(ceil(n/2)) + 2
  T(2) = 1
  T(1) = 0
```

for `T(2)`, it is a base with single comparison before returning. for `T(1)` it is a base without any comparison.

For `T(n)`: You recursively call the method for two halves of the array, and compare the two (min,max) tuples to find the real min and max, which gives you the above `T(n)` equation

```
If n is a power of 2, then we can write T(n) as:

   T(n) = 2T(n/2) + 2
```

This is well explaining itself.

```
  T(n)  = 3/2n -2
```

In here, you solve it with induction:

Base case: for n=2: `T(2) = 1 = (3/2)*2 -2`

We assume `T(k) = (3/2)k - 2` for each `k < n`

 `T(n) = 2T(n/2) + 2 = (*) 2*((3/2*(n/2)) -2) + 2 = 3*(n/2) -4 + 2 = (3/2)*n -2`

(*)induction assumption, is true because `n/2 < n`

Because we proved the induction correct, we can conclude: `T(n) = (3/2)n - 2`

Comment: Hi, how can we do this proof with the k+1 term that is used in the proof by induction?